# Building Nuxt Ionic app give me error not initialization TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'beforeResolve')

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, build, nuxt3

1. install nuxt 3
2. install nuxt ionic
3. then npm run build
4. npm run preview

and I get error :

error caught during app initialization TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'beforeResolve')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue might be of help.
https://github.com/nuxt-modules/ionic/issues/484

tldr: the bug was introduced in `nuxt@3.7.4`, adding the following to nuxt.config.ts fixes the issue

```
experimental:{
  payloadExtraction: false
}
```